# How to specify a background image for PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, html5

Plase see the below code i want to put image in backgroung in table.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="Con" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" renderAs="">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Contact Details" subtitle=""/>
    <apex:image id="theImage" value="BlueAngelBankingWithVaporTrails.jpgf" width="220" height="55"/>
    <b><Marquee><h style="Font-size:20px;Color:Red;">A VF page to show a list of all Contacts.</h></Marquee></b>
    <!--marquee>This text will scroll from right to left</marquee-->
    <!--marquee direction="up">This text will scroll from bottom to top</marquee-->
    <Marquee direction="down" width="750" height="50" behavior="alternate" >
        <b><marquee behavior="alternate" style="Font-size:20px;Color:Green ;">All Contacts list</marquee></b>
    </marquee>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="Edit">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contacts">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Con}" var="c" rows="10" first="4">
                    <apex:column width="500" style="color:green" value="{!c.FirstName}"/>
                    <apex:column width="500" style="color:Blue" value="{!c.LastName}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Email}"/>
                    <apex:column width="800" value="{!c.Phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>  
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Cases">
                <h>All contacts related cases</h>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:inlineEditSupport />
            <apex:pageblockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
            </apex:pageblockButtons>                                                                          
        </apex:pageBlock>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You just want to display the background image behind the pageBlockTable?

Comment: yes...........................

Comment: line 3 code is working now...                                                                    <apex:image id="theImage" value="{!$Resource.bluebird}" width="100" height="55"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualforce component pageBlockTable doesn't support background image, but html table does.

If you refer to [Setting Custom HTML Attributes on Visualforce Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm), you can add this to your pageblocktable:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Con}" var="c" html-background="{!$Resource.bird}">
```

Where `{!$Resource.bird}` is a static [resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_create.htm) in Salesforce

Comment: I have another question in this "" I want to show the related list below the table contact..... the related list is like "case".. how i include into the code

Comment: </apex:pageblocktable>

<Apex:relatedList list="Cases"/>

</Apex:pageblock>

Comment: Please create another question.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use some CSS:

```
<style>
    .tableWithBgImage {
        background-image: url({!$Resource.someStaticImage});
    }
</style>
```

Then, apply the style to the table:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable styleClass="tableWithBgImage" ...>
```

Comment: </apex:pageblocktable> <Apex:relatedList list="Cases"/> </Apex:pageblock>